# Python Dictionaries: If the keys are the same multiply the values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dictionaries, one in the main body of code and one an input. I would like to compare the two dictionaries and if the keys are the same, I want to multiply and print the values. Below is the code I have written thus far.

```
dict_a = {
    'r':100,
    'y':110,
    'a':210
    }

print('Enter The Number Of Items You Wish To Input')

n = int(input())
dict_y={}
print('Enter your dictionary')
dict_y = [ map(str, input().split()) for x in range(n)]

total = []

for word, number in dict_y:
     if word in dict_a.keys():
           prod = dict_y[number] * dict_a[number]
           print(prod)
```

I keep getting the same error and don't know why:

```
           prod = dict_a[number] * dict_y[number]
           TypeError: 'set' object is unsubscriptable
```

A sample input would be:

```
r 10
y 5
a 20
```

The desired output would then be

```
1000
550
210
```

I would really appreciate any help you could give me, Thank You in advance :)

Comment: To test, if a key is in the dict use `word in dict_a`. `split` already returns a list of strings, so no need for `map`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use dict-comprehension instead of list-comprehension:

```
dict_y = [ map(str, input().split()) for x in range(n)]
```

Replace "[...]" to "{...}".

So:

```
dict_y = {map(str, input().split()) for x in range(n)}
```

Next problem is about that you're trying to call list, it is not callable!
If you want to iterate over list ( it's destination is to be dict, not list but that i explained before ), use:

```
for word, number in dict_y.items():
```

For more about dict-comps, look at that documentation: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/

Comment: Yes I meant that, just i tried write it fast and i forgot about that significant thing, anyway thanks for noticing

Comment: Now the error: prod  = dict_y[number] * dict_a[number]
TypeError: 'set' object is unsubscriptable...

Comment: yeah sorry, i've changed them, they should have been prod dict_a and dict_y

Comment: Also when I put in: for word, number in dict_y.items(): the error                    
         for word, number in dict_y.items:
         AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Delete **dict_y={}** and change dict_y declaration into **dict_y = {map(str, input().split()) for x in range(n)}** we'll see if that helps

Comment: @dannyxn in python3 `{map(str, input().split()) for x in range(n)}` will return set of generators, better solution is `dict_y = dict((map(str, input().split())) for x in range(n))`

Comment: @dannyxn it still gives the error  for word, number in dict_y.items: AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
dict_y = dict((map(str, input().split())) for x in range(n))
...
for key in dict_y:
    if key in dict_a:
        print(int(dict_a[key]) * int(dict_y[key]))
...
```

order in `dict` isn't preserved. If you need to preserve order use in `OrderedDict`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly now, really appreciate it

Comment: @ConorBradley for nothing. can you accept my answer?